# Detect randomness: How to calculate this combinatorics formula

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I read [this question about detecting whether a file/partition is encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257362/is-looking-for-plain-text-strings-on-an-encrypted-disk-a-good-test). That got me thinking and I came up with a function that takes a file as input and gives a number between 0 and 1 as output. A high output value means the file looks random and a low value means it's probably not random. I know that detecting if a file is random or encrypted is theoretically impossible and I don't want to discuss the usefulness of my function. I just want to find a way to calculate my function or an approximation thereof in an efficient way, so I can try it out on files on my computer. Efficient meaning here that it would at most take a few seconds to process a file of 1 MB on a modern computer.

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be the number of bytes the file has, let $I = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, N-1\}$ be the indices of the bytes and let $B = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 255\}$ be all possible byte values. The file $d$ can be described as a function from $I$ to $B$.

We define a function that takes $d \in (I \to B)$ and $b \in B$ as input and counts how often byte $b$ occurs in file $d$.
$$
c(d, b) = |\{i \in I\ \ |\ \ d(i) = b\}|
$$
So far so good. Now I'd like to introduce something I'll call a histogram. Histogram is perhaps not the best name, because I don't care which bytes occur how often in a file, but only how often those bytes occur in the file.

An example first. Imagine a file with byte sequence $[10, 5, 5, 5, 120, 10, 3]$.
We have 5 occuring three times, 10 occuring twice and 3 and 120 both occuring once.
The histogram of this file is the multiset $\{3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, \dots\}$. The dots represent more zeroes so that the cardinality of the multiset is $|B|$.
An other example: Take a file with byte sequence $[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]$.
The histogram of this file is the multiset $\{4, 4, 0, 0, \dots\}$.

The function $H$ takes a file $d \in (I \to B)$ and gives its histogram.
Below an attempt to put it in a formula.
$$
H(d) = \underbrace{\{ c(d,b)\ \ |\ \ b \in B\}}_{\mathrm{multiset}}
$$
Now let's define a function $E$, which gives the number of files of size $N$ that have the same histogram as $d$.
$$
E(d) = |\{e \in (I \to B)\ \ |\ \ H(d) = H(e)\}|
$$
I'll try to write $E(d)$ in a way such that it is easier to calculate.
$$
E(d) =\frac{|B|! \cdot N!}
{\prod_{(m, t) \in H(d)} (m!)^t \cdot t!}
$$
The $(m, t) \in H(d)$ requires some explanation. This iterates over a multiset. Here $m$ is the value and $t$ is the number of times it appears in the multiset. So, if we go back to the example of $\{3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, \dots\}$, we iterate over $(3, 1)$, $(2, 1)$, $(1, 2)$ and $(0, 252)$.

And here my final formula, which gives a number between 0 and 1, which should indicate the randomness of the file:
$$
f(d) = \frac{|\{e \in (I \to B)\ \ |\ \ E(e) \le E(d)\}|}{|B|^N}
$$
My question: How do I calculate $f(d)$ or an approximation to this function? It seems very difficult.

Comment: Hmm. This seems way too difficult. I think I'll use the formula for the entropy $g(d) = -\sum_{b \in B} \frac{c(d, b)}{N} \cdot \log_{|B|} \frac{c(d, b)}{N}$ (also a number between 0 and 1) instead of $f(d)$.